# isNumeric caused ajax 304 error in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $( "#withdraw" ).submit(function( e ) {
        $amount = $( "input[name='amount']" ).val();

        if($amount != ''){

            if(!isNumeric($amount)) {
                alert('Amount must be in numerical value!');
                return false;
            }

//ajax here

}
```

If I remove the isNumeric validation everything is working, not sure what is wrong with my application of isNumeric. I expect an alert will pop if the user entered non numberic and 'exit()';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
if(!isNumeric($amount)) {
```

try

```
if(isNaN($amount)) {
```

Comment: but I haven't figured out why isNumeric() is not working in my case.. I know isNaN..